# Java Stream representation of extracting data from jsonobj

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a service that returns me a response that has the below object

```
{
  "features": [
    {
      "name": "climateControl"
    },
    {
      "name": "drivingControl"
    },
    {
      "name": "breakeControl",
      "type": [
        {
          "name": "safety"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "seatAdjustments",
      "type": [
        {
          "name": "motion"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "enginePower",
      "type": [
        {
          "name": "motion"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I need to extract the feature names that are either null or doesn't have any type with name "safety"

I can write something like below

```
List<Features> features = service.getFeatures();
List<String> refinedList = new ArrayList<>();
for(Feature feature:features){
if(feature.getType==null || feature.getType().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("safety") )
{
    refinedList.add(feature.getName());
}
}
```

Looking for a way to do the same using java streams.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` for the `if` conditions and `map` to `getName`, then collect as:

```
List<String> refinedList = features.stream()
        .filter(feature -> feature.getType == null || feature.getType().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("safety"))
        .map(feature -> feature.getName())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```